# In publishing your alexa skill what is the purpose of APP_ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to publish my own skill  but I'm confuse to what is

```
var APP_ID= //your specific APP_ID
```

is this  code above use for accessing your app_ID so what will happen if the customer want to use my skill? are they not going to get access to my skill? Do i need  to keep it undefined? or do I have to put my ID in there?

that's my question, 
hope  you guy's  a good DAy!!

Happy coding Much love and Be Blessed..

KC>DIez
L.E.A.F Striving for a better future for humanity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever alexa call your webservice(or lambda function) it sends you the app-id which enables you to verify the service is actually being called by alexa, and which skill it is, you can not submit a skill without an app-id.

check https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/handle-requests-sent-by-alexa.html

Comment: Leon How Do I close these? also is there any platform's  out there where I could ask all about  alexa skill?